# How should I change the random input to enable absolute randomisation?

Tags: python

I've made a relatively small block of code for a project to generate supposedly randomised card choices and for those two choices to act as choices in a similar fashion to rock paper scissors but they also have an integer attached to those cards so when both player 1 and player 2 get the same colour the number decides the winner. I've added cards into an array and using random.choice(deck) I got it to generate cards. The problem I have now is that I can't seem to get the same card colours for both player 1 and player 2 e.g Yellow1 and Yellow2

```
if access == "true":
    player1_card = []
    player2_card = []
    deck = []
    Y_I = []
    R_I = []
    B_I = []
    play = "true"
    card_colour = ["Yellow", "Red", "Black"]
    
    for i in range(1, 11):
        card_valueY = card_colour[0] + str(i)
        deck.append(card_valueY)
        Y_I.append(card_valueY)
        card_valueB = card_colour[2] + str(i)
        deck.append(card_valueB)
        B_I.append(card_valueB)
        card_valueR = card_colour[1] + str(i)
        deck.append(card_valueR)
        R_I.append(card_valueR)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `random.choice()` in the sample code?

Comment: Link your code with a PLC that has a light quantity detection unit producing random input numbers.

Comment: There's nothing preventing two calls to `random.choice(deck)` from returning values with the same color. You probably didn't try it enough times.

Comment: You should only get the same colors about 1/3 of the time.

Comment: I've tried on multiple occasions as the entire code is meant to repeat until a whole deck of 1-13 yellow, red and black cards have been used from the deck for the game and never have I gotten same colours. The random.choice() pulls from the array deck[]